# Can someone transform a SQL query (SUM DATEDIFF) to a SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm have a situation on oracle sql developer. It doesn't allow Datediff to sum hours.

Is there another alternative for sql oracle? Is it in this case TRUNC and if so how?

```
SELECT DISTINCT al.id
(SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, a.hourBegin, a.hourEnd)) AS Expr1
FROM a INNER JOIN tp ON a.id = tp.idAula
WHERE (tp.type = 'P')) AS total_hour
FROM a INNER JOIN ac ON ac.id = a.id INNER JOIN al ON ac.id = al.id
```

Comment: what datatype is hourBegin and hourEnd ?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you just do math.  Date1 minus Date2 will give you a floating point number.  The integer part is days.  The decimal part is the time.

The equivalent of :

```
select datediff(hour, earlyDateTime, lateDateTime)
```

is

```
select floor(laterDateTime - earlyDateTime) * 24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, a.hourBegin, a.hourEnd))
```

are equal to

```
SUM((a.hourEnd - a.hourBegin)*24)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to do Months use the months_between() function. It helps you by taking into account leap years.

```
SQL> SELECT months_between(to_date('FEB-29-2016', 'MON-DD-YYYY'), to_date('FEB-28-2015', 'MON-DD-YYYY')) FROM dual;
MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('FEB-29
------------------------------
                            12
```

Comment: Downvoted because the OP wants the number of hours between two values and months_between does nothing to provide that.